# iOS ultrasound detection (17khz-22 kHz with sampling Rate of 44.1khz)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, audio-recording, frequency

**iOS ultrasound detection (17khz-22 kHz with sampling Rate of 44.1khz)**

- `detect` the `Ultra sound` and `Show` the `Alert` after `Detecting
  Ultra sound`
- `ultrasound` **Range** is `(17khz-22 kHz)` and `sampling rate` is `44.1Khz`

How can i `detect` and `show` the `alert` for `ultraSound` in `ios` `Objective c`??

Comment: Please have a look at this link. This might help you
http://blog.faberacoustical.com/2009/ios/iphone/iphone-microphone-frequency-response-comparison/

Comment: @KunalGupta...that should be fine , but i want to detect that kind of ultrasound and show the alert for detecting